# Do logevents sent to non-async targets get logged immediately?

Tags: nlog

Can i log an event then in the next line check for its existence?

The "Deferred Message Formatting" section [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/performance) seems to indicate otherwise.
I tried glancing at the code, but it wasn't too clear to me. There are some intermediate steps between when `Logger.Log` is called and when the Target receives the event. It's unclear to me if that all happens synchronously.

Thanks!

Comment: Have updated the wiki-page to be more explicit about the deferring only being activated when using AsyncWrapper-target.

Comment: Oh, that's wonderful. Didn't expect my first question to prompt a change! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NLog is by default synchronous. But if you configure `<targets async="true">` or use the [AsyncWrapper-Target](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/AsyncWrapper-target) then it becomes async.

Have updated the wiki-page to be more explicit about the deferring only being activated when using AsyncWrapper-target.